Stop MacOS apps from opening links in wrong Chrome profile
I recently used WebStorm's debugger connected to a Chrome browser. WebStorm creates its own Chrome profile.
I've since stopped the debugger, exited WebStorm, and deleted that profile.
However, now, whenever I click a web URL in another app on my machine (e.g. Slack or iTerm2) or run open {url}, the debugger Chrome profile gets recreated and the link opens specifically in that profile, rather than in my main Chrome profile.
chrome://version shows the following:



Key
Value




Command Line
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --remote-debugging-port=57520 --user-data-dir=/Users/{user}/Library/Caches/JetBrains/WebStorm2024.2/chrome-user-data-57520 --no-first-run --disable-fre --no-default-browser-check --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end


Executable Path
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome


Profile Path
/Users/{user}/Library/Caches/JetBrains/WebStorm2024.2/chrome-user-data-57520/Default



The command line, which now how references to WebStorm, indicates that "Chrome" has been redefined somewhere in system settings.
I've tried:

Deleting that profile (which keeps getting recreated every time I open a link)
Restarting Chrome
Restarting WebStorm
Restarting the misguided apps (Slack)
Changing MacOS's default browser to Firefox and then back to Chrome

I haven't tried rebooting the computer yet, but honestly, there should be some more reasonable solution.
Any ideas?

Either force-quitting Chrome or replacing Chrome.app with a newly downloaded copy resolved this (not sure which action because I did not test them independently).
